# C++ Demystified Chapter 13 (2004) Jeff Kent: Ifstream program does not return expected output

Tags: c++

C++, expected output that is not outputting is contingent on the existence of students.dat.
If students.dat does not yet exist (and it does not yet), the output would be:
"(infile) = 000000000 (infile.fail()) = 1"

```
#include <iostream>

#include <fstream>

#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()

{

ifstream infile;
infile.open("students.dat");
cout << "(infile) = " << infile << endl;
cout << " (infile.fail()) = " << infile.fail() << endl;
return 0;

}
```

The error message I receive is the following:

```
error C2678: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Thanks for the support, Scott Kelly

Comment: Are you compiling in C++11 (or higher) mode? The semantics for using a stream in an expression [changed in the C++11 standard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool), and could be the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code was never really supposed to work (what does it mean to write an input stream to an output stream?!) but used to work "by accident" because streams in C++03 had an implicit conversion to `void*` which could be used to test the stream's status, and so you could print the value of the `void*`.

In C++11 the conversion has been replaced with an explicit conversion to bool, so the modern equivalent of that code (which is much clearer what it does) is:

```
cout << "(infile) = " << (bool)infile << endl;
```

or:

```
cout << "(infile) = " << static_cast<bool>(infile) << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right and this must be a version issue since my book is so old and I am typing in exactly what it says and it isn't working.  I guess I should learn from a more updated book.